# Is there a way to count number of statements in sqs policy in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs

According to [AWS SQS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-policies.html) the policy for a queue should have a `limit of 20 statements`. Is there a way to count the number of statements for SQS policy in Terraform?

**I have the following scenario:**

I'm using the aws_iam_policy_document data source to combine two policies:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "combined" {
  source_policy_documents = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json,
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_two.json
  ]
}
```

But as the SQS has a limitation on the size of the policy, I want to have a way to get the total number of statements from the previous data source so I can produce a new policy with wildcards. because, for example, if the size of the total SQS policy exceeds 20 statements, then Terraform should produce an error while applying.
The following is just a **pseudocode**:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "test" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.q.id

  policy = (if the statements are less than 20 statements from combined.json then I will take the merged policy) ?data.aws_iam_policy_document.combined.json) : (otherwise I if it is greater than 20 then I will create a new policy with wildcards)
}
```

Comment: Count to do *what* with it? Your question may in fact be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. It would be better if you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the feedback. I added more explanation about the issue.

Comment: Your IAM policy document is in JSON format so you can use [`jsondecode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode) to decode them into a data structure that you can then interrogate using conditional logic.

Comment: This also seems like a situation where [`chunklist`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/chunklist) could be useful, to split the list of statements in your combined policy into chunks of up to 20 statements each.